# How to show a specific hint within Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, hint, obsolete

I'm currently working on improving my coding sensation so I've started adding some extension methods to the types I'm using.

---

I figured out, that I'm doing the same action quite often always with the same attributes.

I want to show this hint when someone calls `ReplaceNewLine("|")`:

> The char you want to remove is `|`. Use the `RemoveNewLine()` extension without any attributes instead.

I tried it with the `[Obsolete(...)]` attribute, but this got shown every time I called the function.

My question is: How can I show a specific hint based on my input within Visual Studio?

**Code:**

```
public static class StringExtension
{
    public static string ReplaceNewLine(this string s)
    {
        return s.Replace("|", Environment.NewLine);
    }

    // show hint if c is |
    public static string ReplaceNewLine(this string s, string c)
    {
        return s.Replace(c, Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

**Apposition:**

- Of course the hint may have the `Obsolete` code (`0618`/`CS0618`) when it is shown, but that's not important for me. I just want to get the hint shown!
- I'm working with `C# 6.0`, `.NET 4.6` and `Visual Studio 2015 RC`.

Comment: Could a ReSharper plugin be a solution?

Comment: @Thomas No, I'm sorry but a ReSharper Plugin won't be a suitable solution for me, as I don't use it. It should be done entirely with code in Visual Studio without adding/installing any additional programs. But Thanks anyway...

Comment: Have you tried using a Wrapper method around 2 private methods, one that is obsolete, but only gets called if the input is "|"?

Comment: The name of the method should imply what it does.
mix of standard usage rules with internal implementation of your code is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2015 this is possible using a Roslyn Diagnostic (and optional Fix). The new Visual Studio 2015 code editor uses Roslyn under the hood to do all it's parsing an the Code Analaysis, Metrics and Refactoring engine is now based on it.

A sample implementation of such an inspection is [given on the Roslyn github page](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Samples-and-Walkthroughs). A full implementation would be a bit much for an answer here on StackOverflow, as it entails a number of steps to go through and amounts to a complete tutorial, but this full tutorial of [something similar is given here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/samples/csharp-diag.pdf). and may be the basis for your work. (ask additional questions later). Code for the [standard rules that ship with the product can be found in the Roslyn GitHub as well](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/tree/master/src/Features/CSharp/CodeFixes).

This piece of code should get you pretty close, but I haven't tested it. Create a standard diagnostic & fix according to the Roslyn SDK totorial and replace the `Initialize` and `AnalyzeNode` methods with (replace the namespace with your own):

```
public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
{
    context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeSyntaxNode, SyntaxKind.InvocationExpression);
}

private void AnalyzeSyntaxNode(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
{
    InvocationExpressionSyntax invocationExpression = context.Node as InvocationExpressionSyntax;
    IMethodSymbol methodSymbol = context.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(invocationExpression).Symbol as IMethodSymbol;

    if (
        methodSymbol != null
        && methodSymbol.Name == "ReplaceNewline" 
        && methodSymbol.ContainingNamespace.Name == "MySampleFix"
        && methodSymbol.OriginalDefinition.Parameters.Length == 1)
    {
        if (invocationExpression.ArgumentList.Arguments.Count() == 1)
        {
            LiteralExpressionSyntax arg =
                invocationExpression.ArgumentList.Arguments[0].Expression as LiteralExpressionSyntax;

            if (arg != null && arg.Token.ValueText == "|")
            {
                Diagnostic.Create(Rule, invocationExpression.GetLocation());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to make something that's backwards compatible with older versions of Visual Studio you can opt to write a custom code analysis rule. This [example rule](http://fxcopcontrib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Dev/FxCopContrib/RegularExpressionDoesNotCompile.cs) takes the input to a call to `Regex.Match` and `Regex.Replace` and gives a warning when it doesn't compile. It would be even simpler to give a warning when it is a constant string.

Visual studio extensions like Resharper and CodeRush offer an SDK which can do things similar to FxCop, but they embed into the IDE like Roslyn does. It may be an option for you to take that approach.

If you want something in the code editor that doesn't use any extension or customization, then adding a `<remark />` to the codedoc is about as much as you can do. In the worst case you could put in a `Debug.Assert(input != "|");` in the method, that way developers will get early warning (at development/debug time) that they're using your API incorrectly.

Comment: If you even can provide a exammple, the answer will be perfect!

Comment: I'm not the king of Roslyn rules (yet) and the sample provided may not be the best available. it should give you enough to get started and ask subsequent questions.

Comment: You're welcome. If you have a finished solution or find required changes, don't hesitate to update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think it is possible, only with the exception of

## emphatic comment

:)

```
/// <summary>
/// Replace specific char with <see cref="Environment.NewLine"/>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="s">input</param>
/// <param name="c">If the char is "|", use the extension method without any parameter instead (<see cref="StringExtension.ReplaceNewLine()" />).</param>
/// <returns>something with maybe new lines.</returns>
public static string ReplaceNewLine(this string s, string c) {...}
```

I dont know any other way to produce hint in pure Visual Studio, with exception of `#warning msg` (and `#pragma`), but they are conditional only by pre-defined build parameters (like `#IF DEBUG` etc) and they go straight to the error list.

Btw & just for fun: you can solve your example by adding default value

```
public static class StringExtension
{
    public static string ReplaceNewLine(this string s, string c = "|")
    {
        return s.Replace(c, Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

**Edit:** [jessehouwing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31137047/628532) answer is much better, this whole answer was more or less a joke about *vigorous comments* :)

Comment: Be careful with "defaults" as they're quite evil. The default value is actually compiled into the calling binary and if you decide to change the default later, all assemblies calling that method need to be recompiled to use the new value.

Comment: Yes, that way it's a compiler feature and not a language feature. it's **bad** ;).

Answer (score -3):

Use single quotes

```
return s.Replace('|', Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: You totally misunderstood the question.